# Unable to build with no apparent build errors

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to learn up on Cordova so I tried to create a simple "Hello World" app with Apache Cordova using the Visual Studio plugin.

When I initially created the app I received a build error which indicated I was missing a .ts file.  It was noted in another SO question that this error was harmless but that creating a blank .ts file would remove the error.  I would not agree that the .ts file is harmless because the app would neither build nor run.

So I added a blank .ts file.  Now the application still will not build but I don't see any discernible warning anywhere.  Here is the build output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\blank.js;scripts\blank.js.map;scripts\blank.js;scripts\blank.js.map
1>  C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Cordova\Test\Test>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Q2JH2S2S.LDY\packages\vs-mda
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am not really sure what is in the directory on the last line.  It's a folder with a handful of .js files, .json files, folders, and .cmd files.  I am not sure what that line is trying to do or if that is where the build error is.

Answer (score 1):

Change the  Tools --> Options --> Project and Solutions --> Build and Run, to get a more detailed output of the build by changing the option in.

But going by the current build output seems like there has been an acquisition issue of the vs-mda, which is VS's node adapter to call into Cordova build.

Try to clear Cordova Cache through Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools and re run the build.

The first build then will take some time as its is going to install the tools again.